# Show that if $f'-cf\ge 0$ and $f(0)\ge 0$ then $f$ is positive

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, inequality

Let $f: \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ such that $f'(x)$ exists over $\Bbb R^+$ and $c: \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ continuous over $\Bbb R^+$.

I need to show that if $\forall t\ge 0, f'(t)-c(t)f(t)\ge 0$ and $f(0)\ge 0$ then $f$ is positive.

I tried to find a link with differential equation of one order.

I let $\forall t\in\mathbb R^+, b(t) = f'(t)-c(t)f(t)$.

But $f'$ could not be continuous and so $b$ could not be too. I don't think I can analyze this correctly.

Do you have a hint ?

Comment: the usual trick is to find an integrating factor such as $e^{\mu(x)}$ and multiply your inequality from both sides with it and see what happens, where $\mu(x)$ is an antiderivative of $c(x)$

Comment: Okay, I will see what could happen !

Comment: Does c have to be positive?

Comment: @doetoe No, $c(t)$ can be negative and/or positive.

Comment: [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Comment: @dezdichado Okay, I got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @dezdichado, I think I got it !

So we have : $\forall t\ge 0, f'(t)\ge c(t)f(t)$.

Let $\mu$ be an antiderivative of $c$ and let us multiplying by $e^{-\mu(t)}$.

We have : $\forall t\ge 0, f'(t)e^{-\mu(t)}\ge c(t)f(t)e^{-\mu(t)}$ then let us integrate both sides from $0$ to $x\in\mathbb R^+_*$.

Now, we get : $$\forall x\in\mathbb R^+, \int_0^xf'(t)e^{-\mu(t)}-c(t)f(t)e^{-\mu(t)}dt = f(x)e^{-\mu(x)}-f(0)e^{-\mu(0)}\ge 0$$

But, $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+, f(0)e^{-\mu(0)}\ge0$. So $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+,f(x)e^{-\mu(x)}\ge 0 $

And $e^{-\mu(x)}\ge 0$. We have : $\forall x\in\mathbb R^+, f(x)\ge 0$.

Comment: good - you should accept your own answer.